# Is a Jewish Male Allowed to Offer Free Hugs to People?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sexuality

On a recent YouTube video, a religious Jew blindfolded himself and stood on the streets of New York City offering people the opportunity to stand with him for peace through a hug. Even though he wanted to send a message of peace to humanity, according to Jewish law, was he allowed to do this?

Please provide a source.

Comment: Pretty sure a real Jew would charge for them :P

Comment: Could this question not be asked without names or links? If you think it may be halachically forbidden, it is Loshon Hora to discuss so publicly.

Comment: I'm sure he asked a Rav. However, I being who I am would think it's forbidden. I don't see any potential leniencies.

Comment: Why do you think it would be different for a male?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5868/759