# Shaking a woman's hand

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, women

1) What are the halachic applications for shaking hands with a woman?

2) Does this apply to only non-Jewish women or Jewish women?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7531/5323

Comment: @Shokhet Is question #2 a duplicate? I'm not so sure. Although perhaps the question should be reversed, since it is essentially trivial that this applies to Jewish women, whereas the applicability of לא תקרבו vis-a-vis a non-Jew is perhaps non-trivial.

Comment: @Fred I'm not sure. There been some [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19832053#19832053) if duplicate parts of a question should be edited out or not.

Comment: @Fred *Now* it's a complete duplicate :O

Comment: @Shokhet why would you want to take out the non-duplicate part and make it a duplicate?  Instead, take out the duplicate part and make it a non-duplicate question.

Comment: @YeZ Check the time stamps of the comments against the revision history. [Revision 2](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/54022/revisions) was made between my second and third comments here.

Comment: @Shokhet I actually looked too quickly - I had thought you removed the non-dupe line.

Comment: If this question is meant specifically regarding whether *a man* may shake a woman's hand, please [edit] the question to make that clear. Don't forget that women are as bound by *Halacha* as men are.

Comment: See my answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/63712/5120