# May Jews do Negiah for social etiquette

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, chilul-kidush-hashem, negia, even-haezer

In Halacha, Jews are generally obligated to refrain from touching other Jews of the opposite gender. My question is, what about cases where refraining from handshaking (not affectionate touch) would be improper social Etiquette, in say a business meeting? If it will cause the other person to look down at religious observance, is it possibly a chillul hashem?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/278/shaking-hands-with-the-opposite-gender/279#279

Comment: Are you implying that breaking halachah isn't a chillul hashem?

Comment: That assumes a handshake is inherently a breaking of Halacha and not merely breaking a Chumrah @ElonMusk